# Value compare Application-defined or Object-defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting an error with this statement.

```
If Sheets("P1").Range(Cells(rngUcell.Row, 11)).Value <> "" And _
  Sheets("P1").Range(Cells(rngUcell.Row, 12)).Value <> "" Then
```

When it hits that check I get

> "Application-defined or Object-defined error"

The statement is getting the values correctly, if I hover over each Range, the first one has stored "R" and the second one has stored "3". So by the logic it should execute the if statement since they are not blank.

Comment: Try splitting them out. Do one compare, then the other. That will help identify the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try (Remove the Range() since Cells() already is returning a range))

```
If Sheets("P1").Cells(rngUcell.Row, 11).Value <> "" And Sheets("P1").Cells(rngUcell.Row, 12).Value <> "" Then
```

Comment: That was it. I've used Range(Cells...etc) before and never received an error about it, I didn't realize what I was saying was redundant.

Thanks Man.

Comment: The other error using the original syntax was that you were referring to the range object in the Sheets("P1") object and the cells inside the active sheet. To properly reference cells inside a range like you were wanting to do would be Sheets("P1").Range(Sheets("P1").Cells(rngUcell.Row, 11)).Value